# Adding zsh ternary operator in npm script - bad subsitution

Tags: zsh, npm-scripts

I am wanting to use a ternary operator in my npm script:

```
"scripts": {
  "build" "node ${%(ENVVAR=nope.foo.bar)}.js"
}
```

So that I can use it like:

```
ENVVAR=nope yarn build
```

And obtain the resulting command of:

```
"node foo.js"
```

However my attempts above (tried parens and square brackets) always yield `bad substitution`

What is the proper syntax to include a ternary operator in my parameter expansion for this (zsh shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script/) state:

> *"The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By default, on Unix-like systems it is the `/bin/sh` command, on Windows it is the `cmd.exe`. The actual shell referred to by `/bin/sh` also depends on the system. As of [npm@5.1.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.1.0) you can customize the shell with the `script-shell` configuration."*

Therefore given that the shell npm utilizes on **nix* is typically `sh` consider the following npm script instead *(Unless of course your npm's [`script-shell`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config/#script-shell) has actually been configured to `zsh`)*:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "[[ $ENVVAR = \"nope\" ]] && val=foo || val=bar; node \"${val}.js\""
}
```

<sub>**Note:** You can check which shell npm is utilizing via the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-config) command: `npm config get script-shell`</sub>

Alternatively, for cross-platform regardless of which shell npm is configured to utilize, consider evaluating a node.js script inline which *"shells-out"* the `node ...` command. For example the following (albeit somewhat verbose) npm script utilizes [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options):

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "node -e \"const val = process.env.ENVVAR === 'nope' ? 'foo' : 'bar'; require('child_process').execSync('node ' + val + '.js', { stdio: [0,1,2] })\""
}
```